# Dynamic overiding of measure axes in dimple.js causing floating droplines

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

eI am creating charts in dimple.js using a dynamic data set. To do this I am using addMeasureAxis for both x and y.

My problem is that I want to change the range of these axes since having the axis cross at the origin often leave my points all in the corner of the graph. To solve this I try set the x/y axis minima to the lowest value of my data by axis.overrideMin.

This gives me a graph scaled better to my data but the axes minima are still not what I had set, instead are slightly lower. As such when I mouseover the drop-lines do not reach the axis, rather they stop at my overrideMin value. Am I overriding incorrectly or can I extend where the drop-lines go to.

```
$scope.svg = new dimple.newSvg("dimple-chart", 800, 600);
$scope.chart = new dimple.chart($scope.svg, $scope.chartData);
$scope.chart.data = $scope.chartData;
$scope.chart.setBounds(60, 30, 500, 330);

var x,y,dataSeries;

x = $scope.chart.addMeasureAxis("x", xStatProperty);
y = $scope.chart.addMeasureAxis("y", yStatProperty);

$scope.chartData = _.sortBy($scope.chartData, xStatProperty);   \\Sorts data
x.overrideMin = $scope.chartData[0][xStatProperty];             \\Overides to min value
$scope.chartData = _.sortBy($scope.chartData, yStatProperty);
y.overrideMin = $scope.chartData[0][yStatProperty];

dataSeries = $scope.chart.addSeries("Team", dimple.plot.bubble);
$scope.chart.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the approach you are using to override, it sounds like you might be using an old version of the library.  Updating to version 2.1 should fix this problem.

Edit:

Following your comment below I've done some more investigation and this is caused by axis value rounding.  Here is an example of the problem:

http://jsbin.com/ricud/2/edit?js,output

In order to ensure that the axes finish on a labelled point, dimple will round the axes to the next ticked value, this probably shouldn't be the case for overridden axes so please create an issue in Git Hub for that.

It's tricky to work around in a flexible way because you need to know the granularity of the axis.  The example above could be fixed by using a floor calculation:

http://jsbin.com/ricud/3/edit?js,output

But that wouldn't work if the axis looked like this:

http://jsbin.com/ricud/4/edit?js,output

The only workaround I can think of relies on some internal API knowledge so is pretty hacky but I think this will work for all cases:

```
chart.draw();

if (x.overrideMin > 0) {
   x._origin = chart._xPixels();
}
if (y.overrideMin > 0) {
   y._origin = chart._yPixels() + chart._heightPixels();
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ricud/7/edit?js,output

Comment: I am using src='http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js' so I believe I am using the up to date version. To give an more detailed example of the problem; if my xStatProperty minimum is 47, the axis minima to appears as ~45 with the droplines stopping at 47. If I try to overrideMin = 46, the same thing happens. However if I use a value < 45 the axis and droplines work fine and they appear where my overrideMin sets them. Perhaps there is a built in cushion because I am using a Bubble chart?